# Logstash: Filtro date hace que falle el parseo

Tags: elasticsearch, stack, kibana

Hola estoy montando un ELK Stack para procesar unos logs que nos envían desde AKAMAI. Un ejemplo:

> 2020-11-18 14:58:27 2.17.200.11 - - - - GET /unaurl.es/N3X3QDOPYNHGPO5R6ZYCEOWCNM.png - 200 1 36513 848 1 80 HTTP/1.1 "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US) AkamaiImageServer VelocitudeMP/1.0;IM/1.0" "-" "-"

El fichero de configuración de logstash es este:

```
input {
    file {
        path => "/var/data/logs/*"
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    }
}

filter {
    grok {
        patterns_dir => ["/etc/logstash/conf.d/patterns"]
        match => {
            "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{IPV4:c-ip} %{USERNAME:cs-username} %{DATA:s-sitename} %{DATA:s-computername} %{CUSTOMIP:s-ip} %{WORD:cs-method} %{URIPATH:cs-uri-stem} %{CUSTOMURIPATH:cs-uri-query} %{NUMBER:sc-status} %{NUMBER:sc-win32-status} %{NUMBER:sc-bytes} %{NUMBER:cs-bytes} %{NUMBER:time-taken} %{CUSTOMPORT:s-port} %{DATA:cs-protocol} %{QS:cs-user-agent} %{DATA:cs-cookie} %{DATA:cs-referer}"
        }
    }
    date {
        match => ["timestamp", "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"]
        target => "@timestamp"
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        index => "index-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    }
    stdout {
        codec => rubydebug
    }
}
```

El fichero de patrones es este:

```
CUSTOMIP (?:%{IP}|-)
CUSTOMURIPATH (?:%{URIPATH}|-)
CUSTOMPORT (?:%{POSINT}|-)
```

El problema es que si quito el filtro date se procesan todos los campos pero claro el timestamp que me coge es el momento de lectura del fichero.

Si dejo el filtro date me da un grok parse failure, cosa que no entiendo pues el match del filtro grok es correcto (sino al quitar date no funcionaría).

Answer (score 0):

Vale el problema no está en el fichero de configuración, acabo de darme cuenta que algunas lineas están bien procesadas y otras no. El problema viene porque en los ficheros de log algunas líneas no casan con la expresión grok y tengo que ajustarla.